# implement a manual increment with just simple SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contain a column `fieldName` and another column `numberOfLine`.

I would like to auto increment `numberOfLine` by 1 taking in condition the `fieldName`. if `fieldName` changed must also the `NumberOfLine` restart count from 1 for an insert request `insert into TableName values ('xxx', ?:NumberOfLigneIncrementedByFieldName)`

I would like to do this with a simple sql request without using `triggers`

for exemple :

[image]

Comment: . . What do you mean by "auto-increment"?  The data is already in a table so you just need to produce the stated number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `row_number()` :

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by fieldname order by ?) as numberofline
from table t;
```

`?` indicate ordering column that specify column ordering.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `row_number()` to calculate the value in a query:

```
select fieldName, row_number() over (partition by fieldName order by fieldName) as NumberOfLine
from t;
```

Normally, the `order by` would be a different column that would specify the ordering that you want.

Comment: This smacks of the 'xy problem' (google it) Instead of some mocked-up, abstract data, explain the real business issue. I'm betting your don't really need/want 'NumberOFLine' stored in the table.